# Creating an instance using the class name and calling constructor

Tags: java, reflection, instantiation

Is there a way to create an instance of a particular class given the class name (dynamic) and pass parameters to its constructor.

Something like:

```
Object object = createInstance("mypackage.MyClass","MyAttributeValue");
```

Where `"MyAttributeValue"` is an argument to the constructor of `MyClass`.

Answer (score 575, accepted):

Yes, something like:

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
Constructor<?> ctor = clazz.getConstructor(String.class);
Object object = ctor.newInstance(new Object[] { ctorArgument });
```

That will only work for a single string parameter of course, but you can modify it pretty easily.

Note that the class name has to be a fully-qualified one, i.e. including the namespace. For nested classes, you need to use a dollar (as that's what the compiler uses). For example:

```
package foo;

public class Outer
{
    public static class Nested {}
}
```

To obtain the `Class` object for that, you'd need `Class.forName("foo.Outer$Nested")`.

Comment: `newInstance()` is a varargs method (just as `GetConstructor()`), there's no need for explicit `Object`-array creation.

Comment: @Joachim: I know it's varargs, but as it can get tricky when you have an `Object[]` argument, I prefer to create the array explicitly in this case.

Comment: clazz.getConstructor(String.class); why String.class here?

Comment: @Neutralizer: Because the OP has a string argument to pass.

Comment: can't it be dynamic? I mean I don't want to hint about the type of arguments beforehand. Is it possible?

Comment: @Neutralizer: Yes, but I was answering a question where it didn't need to be dynamic.

Comment: yeah I know. I wanted to know if can it be dynamic. thanks anyway

Comment: Will using the "Simplename" (no packages, just the class name) work? or must the class name be fully qualified?

Comment: @ycomp: What did the documentation of `Class.forName` and your tests show you? :)

Comment: well docs were inconclusive (it says fully qualified but gives the example of Class "Foo"), which is why I asked - and to write tests for such a simple thing doesn't make much sense when there are probably many people that know the answer to such a simple question.

Comment: @ycomp: I have to say, that *sounds* like "I couldn't be bothered to check" - you could very easily have checked for yourself, and then suggested "You might like to mention that the class name has to be a fully-qualified one."

Comment: @JonSkeet I understand where you are coming from, however it's not quite that simple - I did look at the docs but was confused, but also if I tested it and it worked - ok then it worked - but if it didn't work then I would have been unsure if the problem was due to some lack of configuration or something on my part - often when asking such simple questions, people throw in useful tidbits that really help. That's why a simple "yes that would work - if you do it this way" or "no there's no way", really helps. But my understanding now is that there's no way

Comment: Why is `String.class` a necessary argument to `getConstructor`? Many many examples online do this. A few of the examples show the intent being to get the constructor for a class _actually_ has a `String` parameter for its constructor, while others do not.

Comment: @sherrellbc It's just a simple way of showing an example of passing an argument. Note that the question *asks* about a class with a string parameter in the constructure, so it's not like this has come out of nowhere...

Comment: what is `ctorArgument`?

Comment: @AlexanderMills: The argument you want to pass to the constructor.

Answer (score 117):

You can use [`Class.forName()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) to get a [`Class`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) object of the desired class.

Then use [`getConstructor()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29) to find the desired [`Constructor`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html) object.

Finally, call [`newInstance()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Object...%29) on that object to get your new instance.

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName("mypackage.MyClass");
Constructor<?> cons = c.getConstructor(String.class);
Object object = cons.newInstance("MyAttributeValue");
```

Answer (score 93):

You can use reflections

```
return Class.forName(className).getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(arg);
```

Comment: If using default constructor, remove the String.class parameter value e.g.  return Class.forName(className).getConstructor().newInstance(arg);

Comment: @VijayKumar I think you mean `Class.forName(className).getConstructor().newInstance();` ;)

Answer (score 18):

If class has only one empty constructor (like Activity or Fragment etc, android classes):

```
Class<?> myClass = Class.forName("com.example.MyClass");    
Constructor<?> constructor = myClass.getConstructors()[0];
```

Comment: This is what helped me. `Constructor<?> ctor = clazz.getConstructor(String.class)` didn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 9):

when using (i.e.) `getConstructor(String.lang)` the constructor has to be declared public.
Otherwise a `NoSuchMethodException` is thrown.

if you want to access a **non-public constructor** you have to use instead (i.e.) `getDeclaredConstructor(String.lang)`.

Answer (score 6):

If anyone is looking for a way to create an instance of a class despite the class following the Singleton Pattern, here is a way to do it.

```
// Get Class instance
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("myPackage.MyClass");

// Get the private constructor.
Constructor<?> cons = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor();

// Since it is private, make it accessible.
cons.setAccessible(true);

// Create new object. 
Object obj = cons.newInstance();
```

This only works for classes that implement singleton pattern using a private constructor.

Answer (score 5):

Another helpful answer. [How do I use getConstructor(params).newInstance(args)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9335669/3181500)

```
return Class.forName(**complete classname**)
    .getConstructor(**here pass parameters passed in constructor**)
    .newInstance(**here pass arguments**);
```

In my case, my class's constructor takes Webdriver as parameter, so used below code:

```
return Class.forName("com.page.BillablePage")
    .getConstructor(WebDriver.class)
    .newInstance(this.driver);
```

Answer (score 4):

You want to be using [java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Object...)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Object...%29)

Answer (score 4):

**Very Simple way to create an object in Java using `Class<?>` with constructor argument(s) passing:**

**Case 1:-**
Here, is a small code in this `Main` class:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {

        // Get class name as string.
        String myClassName = Base.class.getName();
        // Create class of type Base.
        Class<?> myClass = Class.forName(myClassName);
        // Create constructor call with argument types.
        Constructor<?> ctr = myClass.getConstructor(String.class);
        // Finally create object of type Base and pass data to constructor.
        String arg1 = "My User Data";
        Object object = ctr.newInstance(new Object[] { arg1 });
        // Type-cast and access the data from class Base.
        Base base = (Base)object;
        System.out.println(base.data);
    }

}
```

And, here is the `Base` class structure:

```
public class Base {

    public String data = null;

    public Base() 
    {
        data = "default";
        System.out.println("Base()");
    }

    public Base(String arg1) {
        data = arg1;
        System.out.println("Base("+arg1+")");
    }

}
```

**Case 2:-** You, can code similarly for constructor with multiple argument and copy constructor. For example, passing 3 arguments as parameter to the `Base` constructor will need the constructor to be created in class and a code change in above as:

```
Constructor<?> ctr = myClass.getConstructor(String.class, String.class, String.class);
Object object = ctr.newInstance(new Object[] { "Arg1", "Arg2", "Arg3" });
```

And here the Base class should somehow look like:

```
public class Base {

    public Base(String a, String b, String c){
        // This constructor need to be created in this case.
    }   
}
```

**Note:-** *Don't forget to handle the various exceptions which need to be handled in the code.*

Comment: Another way is also by clone() the existing java object. This creates a copy of an existing Java object. For this case, you also have to handle the Deep copy or Shallow copy concept.

Answer (score 1):

You can also invoke methods inside the created object.

You can create object instant by invoking the first constractor and then invoke the first method in the created object.

```
    Class<?> c = Class.forName("mypackage.MyClass");
    Constructor<?> ctor = c.getConstructors()[0];
    Object object=ctor.newInstance(new Object[]{"ContstractorArgs"});
    c.getDeclaredMethods()[0].invoke(object,Object... MethodArgs);
```

Comment: How will you know that the very first constructor takes `String` as a parameter? Becomes a little messy when you change constructor order

Comment: @Farid from class documentation

Comment: Still `getConstructor(ClassName.class)` is better, I guess. Even if the order of constructors changes in class, no need to find the position manually

Comment: @Farid -  c.getDeclaredMethods()[0].invoke(object,Object... MethodArgs);
specifies special constructor in some cases you may need this ;but you are right.