# Java: create an object based on content of a string

Tags: java, methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating an instance using the class name and calling constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094575/creating-an-instance-using-the-class-name-and-calling-constructor)

How can I create an object based on the content of a string passed to a method?
For example

```
createObj(String nameclass){
 **class passed** obj;
}
```

Comment: Nearly a duplicate, but the answers in the other article are unnecessarily complicated for the no-args constructor case, where `clazz.newInstance()` is all that is needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Class.newInstance()` to construct an instance of the class.
You will, however, need to obtain the `Class<>` object using `Class.forName(...)`

```
<T> T createObj(String nameclass) throws ClassNotFoundException,
        InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {

    Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>) Class.forName(nameclass);

    // assumes the target class has a no-args Constructor
    return clazz.newInstance();
}
```