# Create and Return an Object Based on a Passed String

Tags: java, string, object, reflection

Is there any way to create and return an object based on a passed string in Java? I want to create objects that are subclasses of a Package class, and do this by calling a method that passes the class name. I could accomplish this with a switch statement easily enough, but if I do it this way, when I add more subclasses of Packages I won't have to adjust the switch statement.

Here's what I have for code:

Package Variable:

```
private Package testPackage;
```

Method Call:

```
createPackage(testPackage, "TestPackage");
```

And the method:

```
Object createPackage(Object curPackage, String packageName)
{   
    Object object = null;

    try
    {
        Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("a.b.c.packages." +packageName);
        Constructor<?> constructor = aClass.getConstructor(new Class[] { String.class });
        object = constructor.newInstance(new Object[] { packageName });
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return object;
}
```

The class is found, but after I run this method and try to call

```
Log.v(TAG, testPackage.getName());
```

I get a null pointer exception. I am writing Android code, I don't think that makes a difference in this situation, though.

Comment: "I want to create objects that are subclasses of a Package class, and do this by calling a method that passes the class name" *sniff* *sniff* looks like code smell... What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094575/creating-an-instance-using-the-class-name-and-calling-constructor you can find better reference here.

Comment: I've already been to that page. That's what I modeled my code after.

Comment: And it's not a code smell, it will save a lot of code if I can implement this short method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a NullPointerException because you don't initialize `testPackage`.

And you have to cast the result :

```
 testPackage = (Package)createPackage("TestPackage")
```

(and you can remove the first parameter, which is not used)

Comment: When I use `testPackage = createPackage(testPackage, "TestPackage");` I get a "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to Package"

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of the NullPointerException?

Comment: Could I do  this with generics? I'm not exactly sure what I'd need to do to set that up. I have used generics before but definitely not in this situation.

Comment: now I get a ClassCastException. I did try this solution earlier as well.

Comment: If you have a ClassCastException, check that a.b.c.packages.TestPackage is a subclass of Package

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone. I for some reason didn't import a.b.c.packages.* so I was having scope issues. I've fixed the problem by Casting to (Package) as I had tried earlier and Thierry and @tkeE2036 suggested. Glad to have finally figured out this simple problem! Thanks again everyone. I'm posting this as a comment since I don't have high enough reputation to answer my own question yet..

Comment: Your answer wasn't the answer to my problem though...maybe I will just to be nice. I don't want to mislead people though

Answer (score 0):

So I believe your problem is that you never assign your variable `curPackage` in your method (at least from what I can tell with the code you've written). You need to assign your testPackage, ie:

```
private Package testPackage = (Package) createPackage("TestPackage");
```

At this point you can just remove your Object parameter since its never used in the method.