# Creating Java object from class name with constructor, which contains parameters

Tags: java

I want to create class object from name, call constructor and create new instance. But I don't know how to send parameters to constructor. My base class is:

```
    public carDao(ConnectionSource connectionSource, Class<Car> dataClass) throws SQLException 
{
    super(connectionSource, dataClass);
}
```

adn what i want do do:

```
    Class myClass = Class.forName("carDao");
    Constructor intConstructor= myClass.getConstructor();
    Object o = intConstructor.newInstance();
```

what should I write in getConstructor()?

Comment: Does this answer you question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094575/creating-an-instance-using-the-class-name-and-calling-constructor

Comment: You should first explain why you want to use reflection, because for 99% of the problems, it's the wrong solution. And respect the Java naming conventions, and put your classes in a package.

Comment: DAO antipattern, you should not invoke singletons.

Comment: @RomanC Where do you see a singleton?

Answer (score 7):

You need to pass classes for your constructor

For example if your constructor has a String parameter

```
  Class myClass = Class.forName("carDao");
  Constructor<?> cons = myClass.getConstructor(String.class);
  Object o = cons.newInstance("MyString");
```

In your case it will be:

```
  myClass.getConstructor(ConnectionSource.class, Class.class);
```

Since getConstructor method declaration is this:

```
 //@param parameterTypes the parameter array
 public Constructor<T> getConstructor(Class<?>... parameterTypes)
    throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
public static <T> T newInstance(final String className,final Object... args) 
        throws ClassNotFoundException, 
        NoSuchMethodException, 
        InstantiationException, 
        IllegalAccessException, 
        IllegalArgumentException, 
        InvocationTargetException {
  // Derive the parameter types from the parameters themselves.
  Class[] types = new Class[args.length];
  for ( int i = 0; i < types.length; i++ ) {
    types[i] = args[i].getClass();
  }
  return (T) Class.forName(className).getConstructor(types).newInstance(args);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass types or arguments in `getConstructor` to get correct constructor. Try maybe

```
myClass.getConstructor(ConnectionSource.class,Class.class);
```

and

```
intConstructor.newInstance(connectionSourceInstance, classInstance);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give the [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) objects to the `getConstructor` method, like this:

```
Class myClass = Class.forName("carDao");
Constructor intConstructor= myClass.getConstructor(ConnectionSource.class, Class.class);
Object o = intConstructor.newInstance(connectionSource, dataClass);
```

For more information, refers to the [documentation of the `getConstructor` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29):

```
public Constructor<T> getConstructor(Class<?>... parameterTypes)
                              throws NoSuchMethodException,
                                     SecurityException
```