# How can I write a method with a fragment class as an argument that will allow me to create a new instance of that fragment?

Tags: java, android

**The Goal**

I'm trying to write a method that would replace the code that I use to swap fragments in order to keep copying and posting to a minimum (and to stay D.R.Y.)

**The Problem**

I get an error when I attempt to use the class that I passed in as an argument to create a new instance of that class.

The error occurs in this line of code, to the left of the operator (equal sign):

```
newFragmentClass new_fragment = newFragmentClass.newInstance();
```

The error it gives me is: "newFragmentClass cannot be resolved to a type".

**Full Code**

```
    private void changeFragment(Class<?> newFragmentClass)
    {
        // Detect the current fragment
            Fragment current_fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
    
        // Create a new instance of the given class, edit later to gracefully handle errors
            newFragmentClass new_fragment = newFragmentClass.newInstance(); 
            
        // Switch to the new fragment
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.detach(current_fragment);
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new_fragment);
            transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            transaction.commit();
            
        // Change the tab background to indicate that the tab is active, reset backgrounds for any other tabs
            findViewById(R.id.page_one_tab).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menu_button_background_active);
            findViewById(R.id.page_two_tab).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menu_button_background);
            findViewById(R.id.page_three_tab).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menu_button_background);
    
    }
    
    // Page One Tab Button Functionality
    public void pageOneTab (View v)
    {
        // Change the fragment to SelectPlayersFragment
        changeFragment(Page_One_Fragment.class);
    }
```

**Attempted Solutions**

I've been searching StackOverflow and the internet at large for quite a while and have not been able to find a solution. A few topics [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094575/creating-an-instance-using-the-class-name-and-calling-constructor) seemed as if they would resolve the problem, but then I ran into an error on the transaction.replace line that I could not find a fix for: "The method replace(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, Object)".

Comment: try this `newFragmentClass new_fragment = new newFragmentClass();`

Comment: @LiaPronina: When I try your suggestion it gives me the same error ("newFragmentClass cannot be resolved to a type") on both mentions of "newFragmentClass" instead of just the first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a more simpler solution would be to pass a `Fragment` as argument, instead of a`Class`, and use it to replace the current fragment. Also, you don't need to detach the current fragment, that is what `replace()` does for you.

Something like this:

```
public void changeFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, "tag");
    transaction.commit();
    //.....
}
```

And you use it like this:

```
changeFragment(new Page_One_Fragment());
```

Comment: I'm using detach because I was having issues with my tabs and fragments behaving strangely whenever I would switch orientation inside of the activity. I would link to the topic where I came across that solution but I can't seem to find it in my history.

Anyways, I am trying your solution now and will report back shortly.

Comment: Your solution works.  
However, I did have to make a change from:  
`changeFragment(Page_One_Fragment.newInstance());` to  
`changeFragment(new Page_One_Fragment());`.

Comment: I'm going to look over the other answers and test them out as well. While yours seems to be simplest solution, I would feel wrong about selecting it without checking/thinking about the others too.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like:

```
private Fragment changeFragment(Class<? extends Fragment> newFragmentClass)  {
    Fragment current_fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
    // Create a new instance of the given class, edit later to gracefully handle errors
    Fragment new_fragment = null;
    try {
         new_fragment = newFragmentClass.newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {            
        throw new RuntimeException(e); // for some reason this fragment loading has failed so crash
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {            
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } 
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.detach(current_fragment);
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new_fragment);
    // ...
```

Comment: When I tried your solution I received the same error as I did on the other two similar answers (`"Unhandled Exception Type IllegalAccessException"`) on the line `Fragment new_fragment = newFragmentClass.newInstance();`

Comment: @Kirk The `newInstance()` method throws two exception `InstantiationException` and `IllegalAccessException`. Do you handle this by either using a `try-catch`  block or a `throws` clause on the method?

Comment: @Luksprong I'm rather new to Android/Java programming and do not have experience with try-catch or throws. When I tried your solution in Eclipse I did notice that it pointed out those two possible resolutions- I tried both. When I tried the try/catch solution I received an error on the transaction.replace line stating that "the local variable new_fragment has not been initialized".

Comment: @Luksprong When I try the `throws` clause, at first it causes another error on the method call, but when I use the same solution for that error it resolves the problem.

Comment: @Luksprong However, I think that because the code from @Andy Res is much simpler (especially with the `throw` clauses) I think I will accept his answer. If I could accept both answers I would.

Comment: @Kirk No problem. I've edited my answer anyway with the full code of the try catch block.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
private <T extends Fragment> void changeFragment(Class<T> newFragmentClass)
{
    ...
    // Create a new instance of the given class, edit later to gracefully handle errors
    T new_fragment = newFragmentClass.newInstance(); 
    ...
}
```

Comment: When I tried your solution I received an error: "Unhandled Exception Type IllegalAccessException" on the right side of the line `T new_fragment = newFragmentClass.newInstance();`

Comment: Luksprog helped me to resolve the error that I was getting (see the comments for that answer). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Because your "newFragmentClass' is only a parameter of method, it's not a type so you can not instance it.
Follow my code to fix your problem

```
private <T extends Fragment> void changeFragment(Class<T> newFragmentClass)
    {
        // Detect the current fragment
            Fragment current_fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content);

        // Create a new instance of the given class, edit later to gracefully handle errors
            T new_fragment = newFragmentClass.newInstance(); 

        // Switch to the player select fragment
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.detach(current_fragment);
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new_fragment);
            transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            transaction.commit();

        // Change the tab background to indicate that the tab is active, reset backgrounds for any other tabs
            findViewById(R.id.page_one_tab).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menu_button_background_active);
            findViewById(R.id.page_two_tab).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menu_button_background);
            findViewById(R.id.page_three_tab).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menu_button_background);

    }
```

Comment: When I tried your solution I received an error: "Unhandled Exception Type IllegalAccessException" on the right side of the line `T new_fragment = newFragmentClass.newInstance();`

Comment: Because in your Page_One_Fragment class you have another Constructor than usual constructor ( public Page_One_Fragment(){...}). This is not a common use. You can refer link http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/using-newinstance-to-instantiate.html to know deep. Hope this help.

Comment: Luksprog helped me to resolve the error that I was getting (see the comments for that answer). Thanks for the help.