# How to map String to Java class?

Tags: java, class

I want to map a String into a Java class.
For example, I want to define my Main class such that it works in the following way:

```
$ java Main SayHello
Hello!
$ java Main SayBye
Bye!
$ java Main SayHola
Error: No such class exists
```

Here is the code.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Call args[0].say()
    }
}

public class SayHello {
    public static void say() {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
    }
}

public class SayBye {
    public static void say() {
        System.out.println("Bye!");
    }
}
```

I know that I could do it by manually mapping each possible value of `args[0]` to a Java class, for example:

```
if (args[0].equals("SayHello")) {
    SayHello.say();
}
```

But is there a way to do this automatically?

Comment: [Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

Comment: I suggest you use a [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) (or a Builder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String className = "com.my.package." + args[0];
    try {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
        Method method = clazz.getMethod("say");
        Object object = clazz.newInstance();
        method.invoke(object);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("Error: No such class exists");
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        System.err.println("Error: You are not allowed to do that");
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        System.err.println("Error: No such method exists");
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        System.err.println("Error: Unable to instantiate");
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        System.err.println("Error: No access to class definition");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.err.println("Error: Illegal argument");
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        System.err.println("Error: Bad target");
    }
}
```

Note: as your `say()` method is static, you can replace:

```
        Object object = clazz.newInstance();
        method.invoke(object);
```

by:

```
        method.invoke(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer here [Creating an instance using the class name and calling constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094575/creating-an-instance-using-the-class-name-and-calling-constructor)

Where you can call class by its name

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
Constructor<?> ctor = clazz.getConstructor(String.class);
Object object = ctor.newInstance(new Object[] { ctorArgument });
```