# Retrieving the data type for an object using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I have an object initialized like :

```
Object obj  = new Object(){
  final String type = "java.lang.Integer";
  final Object value = 6;
};
```

I want to recreate this object as :

```
 Integer i = 6;
```

Is there any way I can get the `type` field of `obj` object and create a new instance using reflection and feed the value in it?

EDIT : Upon extending this question, I find that if I have the object stored in file and retrieve it from file using Jackson using this :

```
Reader reader = new Reader();
MyClass[] instances = reader.readValue(fileName);
```

And `MyClass` is defined as :

```
class MyClass{

  List<Object> fields;
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Now I am iterating the `fields` and converting them into proper objects using the code :

```
public static Class<?> getTypeForObject(Object field) {

    Field returnType = null;
    try {
        returnType = field.getClass().getDeclaredField("type");
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return returnType.getType();
}

public static Object getValueForObject(Object field) {

    Object obj = null;
    try {
        obj = field.getClass().getDeclaredField("value").get(field);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return obj;
}
```

But when I watch the expression `field.getClass()`, it gives me `LinkedHashMap` as its class. I am confused why and if it that Object is internally treated as `Map` what options am I left with if I want to do it with reflection without using an concrete data structures so that everything is generalized.

Comment: Maybe. But you'd just get `obj.value` for `i`; I mean how do you want to use that instance?

Comment: @Elliott : My basic purpose is that if I have an object like `obj` in the given code, i would first want to get the type like `obj.type` and then use probably `Class.forName.newInstance` to get an instance of Integer then using constructors try to set the `obj.value` in `i`

Comment: I understand, that's how you would create some `i`. Now, what do you do with `i`? Because I suspect you want to then pass `i` to something. Maybe print it?

Comment: Yes I do ... into a function that would use `i`.

Comment: @Sourabh I have updated my code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24671025/2764279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will retrieve value of a `type` field from your object:`obj.getClass().getDeclaredField("type").get(obj);`.

Comment: this was something I was looking for. Can you tell me the difference between `obj.getClass().getField("type")` and `obj.getClass().getDeclaredField("type")`? and why the latter works and not the former?

Comment: `getField` searches only for public fields, `getDeclaredField` searches for all kind of fields (public, private, protected, default).

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can. But since the type of `obj` is an anonymous class extending `java.lang.Object`, you can't reference its fields (`type` and `value`) directly, only via reflection.

Here's the code how you could do it:

```
    String type = (String) obj.getClass().getDeclaredField("type").get(obj);
    Object value = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField("value").get(obj);

    // Type can be anything, so in order to instantiate it,
    // we have to assume something. We assume it has a constructor
    // which takes only a String value.
    Object recreated = Class.forName(type).getConstructor(String.class)
            .newInstance(value == null ? null : value.toString());
    System.out.println(recreated);
```

Comment: The answer you have given is absolutely correct but since bananan posted the some minutes before you I will have to give him the correct answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just have a look at **new updated** code :

```
Object obj = new Object() {
    final String type = "java.lang.Integer";
    final Object value = 6;
};

public void demo(){

    try {
        Field typeField = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField("type");
        typeField.setAccessible(true);
        String type = typeField.get(obj).toString();
        Field valueField = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField("value");
        valueField.setAccessible(true);
        String value = valueField.get(obj).toString();
        Class intClass = Class.forName(type);
        Constructor intCons = intClass.getConstructor(String.class);
        Integer i = (Integer) intCons.newInstance(value.toString());
        System.out.println(i);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

> **Note :** got help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6094575/2764279) question.

**UPDATE:** Now getting the `type` and `value` from `Object obj`.

Comment: Yes this what I will try to do but why question is how will I retrieve `type` and `value` from `obj`?

Comment: @Sourabh - the way I've showed you in my answer right above.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can use `Class.forName`.

For example, instead of Integer, consider a Person--

```
public static String getObjectType()
{
    return "Person";
}
```

---

```
final String type = getObjectType();

Class.forName(type);  //returns the `Person.class`, if Person.class is in classpath if not throws a `ClassNotFoundException`
```

To create a Person object from the Person.Class you can do something like this -

```
final Person p = Person.class.getConstructor(Integer.class, String.class).newInstance(age, name);
```

Comment: But I want be knowing whether its the person class. Infact the Person.class is something my type field from obj will give me and using that return type i will be able to get an instance using the method you suggested.

Comment: yes, you can pass the name of any class as a `type`. Please take a loot at my edited answer.