# Start Activity with New Intent using dynamic class name

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to do this in android:

```
String anewactivity="Zero";
Intent NewActivity = new Intent(context, anewactivity.class);
```

I tried to do that but it gave me an error.
Is it possible in some way?

Thanks!

I saw the answer that you showed me when i was posting my question.
but the other answer don't launch for me the new activity does it?

Comment: This is supported in Java and is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094575/creating-an-instance-using-the-class-name-and-calling-constructor).

Comment: you need the fully qualified path to the class, and then you can use intent.setClassName(context, anewactivity);

Comment: ah k thanks! so whats the best method? the linked answer or the below reply (java reflection). any idea? :)

Comment: ok got it! i am not in need of using the constructor so I'll be using the answer below!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use java's reflection methods:

```
Class activityClass = Class.forName("com.something.Zero");
```

Comment: marvelous... this realy nice