# From Class<? extends X> to X

Tags: java, reflection

I am currently working on some reflexion stuff and I'm just a beginner at it.

I got this :

```
List<X> list;
Set<Class<? extends X>> set;
```

And I want to do something like this :

```
for (Class<? extends X> classx : set) list.add(classx);
```

But i couldn't find anything on how to achieve it.
Can someone help me?

Comment: `X` and `Class<? extends X>` are very different types. As written, you need at least to create a new instance of `Class<? extends X>` using reflection. Is your question about how to create an instance when you have a `Class<?>`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating an instance using the class name and calling constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094575/creating-an-instance-using-the-class-name-and-calling-constructor)

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve such behavior with that input data. `List<X>` list expected the instance of class X, but you're trying to add the object of Type `Class<? extends X>`.
Let's imagine that type X is Number(for simplicity), we have Double, Integer, Character and etc, children of Number.
So, you're doing the next thing:
You want to add the object of type `Class<Integer>` to list which can hold only Numbers(not a `Class<Integer>`, `Class<Double>` and so on). The only thing you can do, it's create the instance of `Class<Integer>`, `Class<Double>` this way, using reflection:

```
List<X> list = //some values;
Set<Class<? extends X>> set = //some values;
for (Class<? extends X> classx : set) list.add(classx.newInstance());
```

But that's so bad idea to use reflection in such way. 
Maybe you meant something this:

```
List<Class<X>> list = //some values;
Set<Class<? extends X>> set = //some values;
for (Class<? extends X> classx : set) list.add(classx);
```

Because still the 
`Class<X>` is not the same as `Class<? extends X>`.
But maybe you meant something like this:

```
List<X> list = //some values;
Set<? extends X> set = = //some values;
for (X elem : set) list.add(elem);
```

Last one looks nice and it should work.

Comment: But I do need to have a List<X> because I need to invoke some methods on these objects.
Having a Set<? extends X> is exactly what I'm trying to get.

Comment: @MaëlGrivot so, let me ask some questions. First of all: do you really have Set<Class<? extends X>> set, maybe you have Set<? extends X> set ? If 1 variant - first of all you need to instantiate you Class<? extends X> because in Java variable Class<? extends X> someVar is the object of type Class<? extends X>(let's call it Class Object), not the same as object of type ? extends X. The Class Objects have methods for reflection(example newInstance() - which creates from this Class Object - the Object of type which specified in brackets of it.)

Comment: Yes I do have a Set<Class<? extends X>> which contains a list of classes that extends an abstract class.

Comment: @MaëlGrivot so, the only option it's to iterate from this set of classes and call method newInstance()(to instantiate that class) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html - look here. And add them to your result list - if it's your task. Maybe you can share the idea: what are trying to implement?(I mean the main task)