# How to create object with variable object name in Java

Tags: java

How to create an object from a class, but the object name should be variable and taken from a given string.

```
String objName = "customerA";
objName = new Customer("A");
```

Then I would like to use the object like (e.g.)

```
Object obj = getObjByName("customerA"); // is it possible to retrieve an object by name?
obj..getName();  //retrieve name of the customer
```

Comment: State your actual task. This example does not make any sense.

Comment: Use a Map<String, Customer> to store and retrieve your objects. Your first statement should be: `Customer c = new Customer(objName)`

Comment: perhaps you wish to create a Customer Factory class that returns a different Customer object based on a given string?

Comment: If you truly wish to go down the path of creating objects based on their qualified name, then you'll want to look into [Java Reflection](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javareflection-1536171.html).  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6094602/1601729) as an example.  But note that this is generally regarded as bad practice unless you have no alternative option.  It is most likely that there is a better way to do what you want.

Comment: Pursuing that further, why do you want to create an object from its name?

Comment: Your first code block makes no sense.  You're creating a string variable and setting it to "customerA".  Then you're clobbering the string variable with a new value -- one that's not valid since it's not a string (and compilation of that code would fail.)  Pleas ALWAYS check that code compiles before posting it!  Please read  [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and how to post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I know, that this code is not working, but wanted to have a code 'description' of what want to do.

Comment: Read through the other comments and the answers of the existing question and will go with the Map solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use map for this purpose. 
As i can understand, variable name depends on the value of the string but object type remains the same. You can do something like as follows :

```
String variableName = "name";
Map <String,Customer> customerMap = new HashMap <>();
customerMap.put (variableName,new Customer ());
Customer ref = customerMap.get (variableName);
ref.getName ();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a Factory Class for your customer objects. Then when you need an object of a certain type, you simply pass the String containing your desired class and the Factory returns the object.

```
public class CustomerFactory {

private CustomerFactory()
{
    //do nothing
}

public static Customer CreateCustomer(String customerType)
{
    if(customerType == null)
        return null;
    else if(customerType.equals("CustomerA"))
        return new CustomerA();
    else if(customerType.equals("CustomerB"))
        return new CustomerB();
    else
        return null;
}

}
```

This works as long as your Customer's all extend the parent Customer class. Then you could use the factory to give you back a class object of your choosing based on the String passed in like the following

```
CustomerA obj1 = CustomerFactory.CreateCustomer("CustomerA");
CustomerB obj2 = CustomerFactory.CreateCustomer("CustomerB");
```