# Is it possible to create the objects of class dynamically?

Tags: java, object, dynamic, instantiation

for example, i have 10 classes created with some methods in it. now, i want to create a method which takes one of these classname as input parameter in String format and instantiate that class.

```
public void instantiateclass(String Classname)
{

// this method should instantiate the given classname

 }
```

is this possible in java reflection? or any other concepts in java?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating an instance using the class name and calling constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094575/creating-an-instance-using-the-class-name-and-calling-constructor)

Comment: this worked Jonathon..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. you can change your method to return an `Object`.

```
public Object instantiateClass(Class<?> clazz)
{
    Object instance = null;
    try {
        instance = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException
                | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

This can be easily done in c# by below code

```
private static object CreateInstanceByClassName(string className)
{
  var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

  var type = assembly.GetTypes()
    .First(t => t.Name == className);

  return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
 }
```

Above code assumes that the class is present in same assemble