# Is there a way to get an instance of a class given the .class

Tags: java

Is there a way for me to instantiate an object, given its class? So in the given scenario, I would have a value for `class` and need to get a value for `object`.

```
//This is given
Class<?> class;

//This is not given
Object object;
```

Also, is it possible to generically cast an object to type `class` or make `object` not be of type `Object` but be of whatever type `class` is?

Comment: I would try the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html) of the `Class` class, hint: get a constructor and check its methods (or, better[?], search this site as probably done for previous comment by pochopsp)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, in this other question you can find more information: [Creating an instance using the class name and calling constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6094575/12508080)

You could do something like this:

```
Class<?> clazz = String.class;
Object object = clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
```

Comment: Thanks! However, when I put this into Android studio, it threw a NoSuchMethodException.

Comment: Is it possible that your constructor requires passing parameters?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to make a program where you inherit the class to use it. You specify the class in the subclass, so I can't predict the constructor.

Comment: @getrithekd You need to invoke a constructor, so you need to be able to predict it. In practice, this is done in a few different ways, such as guessing arguments from a set of candidates based on their type, or by examining custom annotations on the formal parameters of the constructor. This functionality is typically provided by [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) frameworks like Spring, so you may not need to build your own.